# How to align the text field items by 2 columns in a row in oracle apex5.0, i have attached sample picture

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

How to align the text field items by 2 columns in a row in oracle apex5.0.

[image]

Comment: I can't see a picture?

Answer (score 0):

did you try to use Page Designer in 5.0 
you can do it by using drag and drop

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t3UDGBJ4UCY